# how to unlock bluetooth service in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: bluetooth, 15.10, unlock

After installing ubuntu 15.10 i have some problems with bluetooth file sharing:my PC has established BT connection to Samsung phone and I can send files from my PC to phone, but can't do it otherwise. When my phone sends file my PC shows lock beside bluetooth simbol.Thank you in advance